# Magento 2 Apply discount code is not working on checkout page

Tags: magento, magento2

[image]
I am facing issue when apply discount code on magento 2 checkout page.
On Cart Page Apply discount code is working fine but it is not working on checkout Page.

404 Bad Request

[image]

Comment: check console error

Comment: 404 Bad Request is showing and also 
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

static/version1591789971/frontend/Alothemes/kuteshop2/en_US/Magento_SalesRule/js/action/set-coupon-code.js:62

Comment: Please add screen-short

Comment: Image attached please check